# Instead of $.each want to use Array.find

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ecmascript-6, geolocation

I want to use Array.find instead of $.each so it stops looping once it has found the result, but I cannot figure out the correct syntax to return the zipcode.

```
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var latLng   = new google.maps.LatLng( 
            position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        geocoder.geocode({
            'latLng': latLng
        }, function (results, status) {
            var searchAddressComponents = results[0].address_components;
            var zipcode = "";

            //searchAddressComponents.find(function() {
            //});

            /*  function isZipcode() {
                    if(results[0].address_components.types[0]=="postal_code"){
                        zipcode = element.short_name;
                    }
                }*/

            //THIS WORKS BUT WANT TO USE ARRAY.FIND to return Zipcode
            $.each(searchAddressComponents, function(){
                if(this.types[0]=="postal_code"){
                    zipcode = this.short_name;
                }
            });

        }); //END OF GEOCODER
    });
```

Comment: Could this maybe solve your problem?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962948/jquery-end-each-loop-inside-of-click

Comment: you can use return false where condition true

Comment: why would you just not use a `for loop` for this simple use case?

Comment: @Steve I just want to know how it would be done using Array.find with JS ES6

Comment: `searchAddressComponents.find(address => address.types[0] =="postal_code").short_name`

Comment: be aware that according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find `array.find()` is not compatible with IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to skin this cat. But if you want to use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), here's how:

```js
zipcode = searchAddressComponents.find(component => component.types[0] == "postal_code").short_name;
```

---

For pre-ES6, the function is as follows

```
zipcode = searchAddressComponents.find(function (component) {
  return component.types[0] == "postal_code";
}).short_name;
```

Comment: without using es6 arrows how would you use array.find?

Comment: @Fawn The question asked for ES6 code, but I've added to the answer for you.

Comment: I know I selected it as the right answer. Just wasn't sure if it would be '    var zipcode = searchAddressComponents.find(function(el) {
     return el.types[0] == "postal_code".short_name;
    });' trying to understand the code

Comment: @Fawn When I find ES6+ code unintuitive, I use [Babel](http://babeljs.io/repl) to compile it to something (hopefully!) more familiar. It doesn't always work, but with this it definitely does.

Comment: thanks you da best! Trying to learn JS and understand it fully. Babel is so cool thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

This should work (assuming you have access to ES6 syntax, such as arrow functions):

```
const zipcode = searchAddressComponents.find(
  component =>  component.types[0] === 'postal_code'
).short_name;
```